# How to convert a string to integer in php

Tags: php

I have a variable `$var1 = "21,855.00"`. I already tried using `preg_replace` and `str_replace` but I could not really achieve what I was looking for. 
I wish to echo it as `21855`. How can I do that using PHP?

Comment: `$var1 = 21,855.00` is invalid code. Do you mean to say you have a *string* `"21,855.00"`?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. Thank  you for the correction.

Comment: That stresses how important is to ask a question with your real codes and not hypothetical codes. You just rendered a 9 up-votes answer useless. If your typo was a comma that would still hold, but your typo was in those quotes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has significantly changed from its original form, rendering most of the existing answers useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking note:

If its a literal `string` like:

```
$var1 = '21,855.00'; // string(9) "21,855.00"
```

You can also do it this way:

```
$var1 = '21,855.00';
$var2 = filter_var(strtok($var1, '.'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $var2; // 21855
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7sPIty)

Or with regex:

```
$var1 = '21,855.00';
$var2 = (int) preg_replace('/(?<=\d),(?=\d{3}\b)/','', $var1);
var_dump($var2); // int(21855)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use **[intval()](http://php.net/intval)**

```
$var1 = 21855.00;
$varInt= intval($var1);
```

**You can also do**

```
$varInt= (int)$var1;
```

**You can also use `floor()` to round down**

```
$varInt= floor($var1);
```

**You can also use `ceil()` to round up**

```
$varInt= ceil($var1);
```

**You can also do**

```
settype($var1, "integer");
```

haha i must be having a lot of time to waste today :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways;

```
$myFloat  = 123456.78;
$firstWay = intval($myFloat);
$secondWay= (int) $myFloat;
```

You can use intval() as Hanky stated or cast the value to integer with using `(int)`. I believe using `(int) $myFloat` is faster than using `intval($myFloat)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this also -

```
$var1 = (int) 21855.00;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try intval()
eg:

```
$val = 21855.00; 
$val_int = intval($val);
```